# How do I create a restkit .20 response descriptor without an object mapping?

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to PUT an object to the server, then appropriately handle the server's response.

My code is hitting the server successfully:

```
[rkManager putObject:self
                path://Path generated
          parameters:nil
             success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                 //handle success
             }
             failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                //handle failure
             }];
```

But once it hits the server, when it comes back, the error handler is called -- always.  Even though I'm getting a 200 response, it calls the error handling.  I believe this is because I haven't defined a response descriptor to tell it that it can take a 200 code.  The problem is, the server returns an empty body when I successfully put -- and I can't use a nil mapping object when I create the response descriptor.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RestKit to do the mapping and create the request to send:

```
[rkManager requestWithObject:... method:... path:... parameters:...];
```

And then use the underlying AFNetworking classes to actually send the returned request.